# using google doc api to authorize users/create google docs

Tags: node.js, google-oauth, google-docs, google-docs-api, google-developers-console

I have a node.js application (based largely on an index.js file with the routes, db.js file with database calls and multiple pages in html/css/javascript) where users can create an account and log in. Within the app there is a list of names visible when people have logged in (the list of names varies with whoever logs in). My objective is to use the google doc api to create an external google doc (that can be linked from within the app) for each name in the aforementioned list.

I am currently trying to follow the documentation at https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/nodejs, and while I understand it doesn't mean to create google docs, my main question is about the authorisation processes, namely the parts with fs.readFile, and the authorize and getNewToken functions. I don't understand the fs.readFile bit since all kinds of clients with different kinds of credentials will be using the app, and to me it doesn't make sense to have one credentials.json file with one set of credentials.

Would anyone have a better idea of how a user of the app could authenticate themselves, and thus allow code to make google docs in their drive?

Thanks

Comment: Could you specify more your question? As I understood your users need Gmail account to use Google services..

Comment: I envision my app to have a list of names e.g. Sarah, Jane, Jessica etc., and next to each name there should be a link to a dynamically created google doc (I would presume these google docs need to be in a drive/folder accessible by the google account of the authorised user). In the app names can be added to the list at any time, and each time this happens a new google doc for that person should be dynamically created. 

This is the end goal - but I assume I would first need to know how I can authorise the google account of a user of the app - this is what I'm currently stuck on.

Comment: Check this link [Google Auth Library for Node.js](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs), it will guide you step by step. I hope this helps.